# Is it possible to get gif thumbnails from Brightcove videos?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, brightcove

Is it possible to get gif thumbnails from Brightcove videos?

I have a client using the Brightcove Video Cloud platform, and in a new design we would like to have the ability to show a clip of the video in gif form, when the user hovers a thumbnail. In much the same way that YouTube does.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no out-of-the-box implementation of thumbnail scrubbing for the Brightcove player at this time.

We created an open-source sample [Thumbnail Previews Plugin](https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-thumbnails) that implements displaying the thumbnails, however you are required to generate them and make them available on your own.  We also have a [support document](https://support.brightcove.com/display-thumbnail-previews-plugin) outlining how to use the plugin and options for generating the plugins.

It looks like this plugin was written for Brightcove Player v5.x but I'm not seeing anything in it that wouldn't work with the latest player. (v6.x).

Disclaimer: I am employed by Brightcove